# Adding twig page to popup marker in leaflet causes syntax error

Tags: leaflet, twig

I use leafletjs to render map in symfony app. My problem is when I include twig page as popup to the map marker the map disappears.

I tried to add one element (`{{ dreq.dreq_identifier }}`) in my twig and it works fine! the issue is when I add multiple lines.

Here is my code

```
<div id="map" style="height: 600px;"></div>
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>
        $(window).on('load', '', function (e) {
            if (document.getElementById('map')) {
                let map;
                //set up the Leaflet.js map
                map = L.map('map', { center: [{{ data[0]['dreq_startLatitude'] }}, {{ data[0]['dreq_startLongitude'] }}], zoom: 13 });
                let sitesGroup = L.layerGroup();
                let customIcon = {
                    iconUrl:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png",
                    {#iconUrl:"{{ asset('assets/css/images/marker-icon.png') }}",#}
                    iconSize:[20,30]
                };
                let myIcon = L.icon(customIcon);
                let iconOptions = {
                    icon:myIcon
                };
                // tiles etc
                L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        attribution: 'kalvo'
                    }
                ).addTo(map);
                {% for element in data %}
                    var marker = new L.Marker([{{ element.dreq_startLatitude }}, {{ element.dreq_startLongitude }}], iconOptions).addTo(map);
                    var popup = L.popup()
                        // .setContent(""<img alt="orange" align="bottom" width="24px" height="24px" src="/assets/img/orange.gif"/>");
                        .setContent("{% include 'dreq/maps/_popover_carto_dreqs.html.twig'
                            with {'dreq': element} %}");
                    marker.bindPopup(popup);
                {% endfor %}
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

And in dreq/maps/_popover_carto_dreqs.html.twig I added this code :

```
{{ operator(dreq.operator) }} channel: <b>{{ dreq.channelId }}</b> - file: <b>{{ dreq.fileName }}</b> - id: <b>{{ dreq.dreq_identifier }}</b>
  - protocol: <b>{{getProtocolsLabel(dreq.dreq_protocol)}}</b> - direction: <b>{{dreq.direction}}</b>file name: <b>{{ dreq.dreq_fileName }}</b> - file size: <b>{{ dreq.dreq_fileSize | formatSize }}</b>status: <b>{{ dreq.dreqStatus }}</b> - packet: <b>{{ dreq.dreqPacketTechnoLabels }}
```

When I click on F12 I have this problem:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does it show any error?, The code seems to be correct.

Comment: @JuanCastillo it shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token I will add the error content in my post

Comment: can you try with usign a template literal?, I mean, setting the values in variables and then adding them into the method but as template literal

Comment: .setContent("hello world"); works but .setContent("hello (+enter button)
 world"); doesn't work

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the return line, javascript consider it as not ended line. any idea how to convert it my include to string ?  I think it probably works .

Comment: I say something like:  let popupContent= "{% include 'dreq/maps/_popover_carto_dreqs.html.twig' with {'dreq': element} %}"; and then  popup.setContent( popupContent ); , besides, it would be better if you could see the value of "popupContent" before (console.log( popupContent )) to check if it is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252941/discussion-between-juan-castillo-and-zackzulg).

Comment: You need to strip all the  `\r`'s and `\n`'s if you want to pass that to JS

Comment: is there any way to do it even if I use twig operators like if/else ?

Comment: Assign the include to a variable, then replace the newlines in the variables whilst passing it to JS

Comment: I did it this way : {% set content %}{% include 'maps/_popover_carto_dreqs.html.twig' with {'dreq': element} %} {% endset %}
var popupContent = "{{ content }}";
var arr = popupContent.split("\n");
console.log(arr);
Result : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". And red line on popupContent value.

Comment: You need to remove the newlines *before* passing it to JS. Multiline assignment is not a thing in JS

Comment: @DarkBee my problem is I have many if else statement and to have only one line in my twig popup is not very clean. I guess the best way is to inject my twig with hidden div in main twig and add its html to my popup in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several solutions, I guess the best until now (even if it's not clean) is to inject my twig popup in div element and add its html in popup.

```
    <div id="map" style="height: 600px;"></div>
    {% for element in data %}
        <div id="{{ element.identifiant }}" hidden>
            {% if type == 'dreq' %}
                {% include 'maps/_popover_carto_dreqs.html.twig' with {'dreq': element} %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Js :

```
{% for element in data %}
 var marker = new L.Marker([{{ element['latitude'] }}, {{ element['longitude'] }}], iconOptions).addTo(map);
 var popup = L.popup().setContent($("#{{ element.identifiant }}").html());
 marker.bindPopup(popup, {maxWidth: 600});
 {% endfor %}
```